# Function group_by for an emmeans test combine one of my factor

Tags: r, anova, emmeans

I'm doing a 3-way ANOVA that shows me a significant interactive effect of my 3 factors, I anted to do a post-hoc test with emmeans_test to see if the pairs of my different groups are significantly different.
The problem is that my data frame look like this (not the entire data frame, but to see how many different groups I have) :

| temperature | quality | quantity | growth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | S | 0.1 | 150 |
| 20 | S | 0.3 | 50 |
| 20 | S | 0.6 | 160 |
| 20 | S | 0.9 | 80 |
| 20 | S | 1.5 | 95 |
| 28 | S | 0.1 | 120 |
| 28 | S | 0.3 | 54 |
| 28 | S | 0.6 | 70 |
| 28 | S | 0.9 | 94 |
| 28 | S | 1.5 | 74 |
| 20 | Y | 0.1 | 200 |
| 20 | Y | 0.3 | 64 |
| 20 | Y | 0.6 | 80 |
| 20 | Y | 0.9 | 87 |
| 20 | Y | 1.5 | 95 |
| 28 | Y | 0.1 | 87 |
| 28 | Y | 0.3 | 55 |
| 28 | Y | 0.6 | 92 |
| 28 | Y | 0.9 | 108 |
| 28 | Y | 1.5 | 121 |

I want to compare by pairs to see if 2 groups are different so I used `emmeans_test`, but when I run my script, the function `group_by` group my factor quantity as one unique quantity (0.830) whereas I have 5 differents :

```
library(rstatix)
> res1 <- donnees_tot_g_J4 %>%
+   group_by(quantity, quality) %>%
+   emmeans_test(growth_rate ~ temperature, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")
> res1
# A tibble: 2 × 11
  quantity quality term        .y.         group1 group2    df statistic         p    p.adj p.adj…¹
*    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>       <chr>       <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>  
1    0.830 S       temperature growth_rate 20     28        98      4.22 0.0000537  5.37e-5 ****   
2    0.830 Y       temperature growth_rate 20     28        98      3.05 0.00292    2.92e-3 **     
# … with abbreviated variable name ¹​p.adj.signif
```

And here is my code :

```
structure(list( quality = c("S","S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S",
"S", "S", "S", "Y", "Y", "Y",
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"S"), quantity = c(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9, 0.9, 
0.9, 0.9, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.1), temperature = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28),growth_rate = c(0.303800071834841, 0.405269291837872, 0.316864747623708, 
    0.303800071834841, 0.352098906853808, 0.37289228981091, 0.382620123855391, 
    0.444775904433979, 0.409541745203879, 0.396477069415012, 
    0.472100291701688, 0.451919285802152, 0.444775904433979, 
    0.437402052060633, 0.52882661034269, 0.533795710392497, 0.541052497667245, 
    0.510531280665662, 0.533795710392497, 0.622339329512085, 
    0.627290489167077, 0.601386996896272, 0.148530350448613, 
    0.22732788723803, 0.191530869757777, 0.181562374726831, 0.354194957377592, 
    0.375858237686643, 0.34006122020639, 0.17110742318728, 0.160116090892034, 
    0.160116090892034, 0.210176015665816, 0.609895236463043, 
    0.591124373918946, 0.58187326824239, 0.0378568479840844, 
    0.126892202895244, 0.0152090656484838, 0.0152090656484838, 
    0.0585326533474545, 0.0585326533474545, 0.0775525505364441, 
    0.126892202895244, 0.0951622248242906, 0.0585326533474545, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 142.231, 0, 0, 142.231, 
142.231, 142.231, 142.231, 142.231, 142.231, 142.231, 142.231, 
142.231, 142.231, 142.231, 142.231, 142.231, 142.231, 142.231, 
142.231, 142.231, 142.231, 142.231, 142.231, 142.231, 142.231, 
142.231, 142.231, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -106L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: To make code reproducible, you could also add which packages you load e.g. `library(emmeans)`.

Comment: Can you add the data with `dput`?

Comment: I just edited my post with the library and my data

Comment: Maybe just the example you posted, but here I'm finding an error b/c `growth_rate` has only 88 observations, other variables 106

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `quantity` variable is numeric, so it gets reduced to its mean by default. If you want the values kept separate, add `cov.reduce = FALSE` to the `emmeans_test` call.

#### Addendum

I had mistakenly assumed that `emmeans_test` was patterned after `emmeans::emmeans`.

Here is (perhaps) an equivalent analysis
using the **emmeans** package itself. (I am using only the first 87 rows
of the data, as the data in the OP is corrupt).

```
> mod <- lm(growth_rate ~ temperature * quantity * quality, data = dat)
> library(emmeans)
> EMM <- emmeans(mod, ~ temperature | quality * quantity, cov.reduce = FALSE)
> test(pairs(EMM), by = NULL, adjust = "bonferroni")
 contrast                      quality quantity estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
 temperature20 - temperature28 S            0.1   -0.877 19.5 79  -0.045  1.0000
 temperature20 - temperature28 Y            0.1  -56.369 21.6 79  -2.610  0.1084
 temperature20 - temperature28 S            0.3  -14.744 15.8 79  -0.935  1.0000
 temperature20 - temperature28 Y            0.3  -69.216 17.8 79  -3.896  0.0020
 temperature20 - temperature28 S            0.6  -35.543 12.9 79  -2.755  0.0728
 temperature20 - temperature28 Y            0.6  -88.486 14.0 79  -6.340  <.0001
 temperature20 - temperature28 S            0.9  -56.342 14.9 79  -3.776  0.0031
 temperature20 - temperature28 Y            0.9 -107.756 14.2 79  -7.604  <.0001
 temperature20 - temperature28 S            1.5  -97.941 27.4 79  -3.573  0.0060
 temperature20 - temperature28 Y            1.5 -146.297 24.4 79  -6.007  <.0001

P value adjustment: bonferroni method for 10 tests
```

However, it is hard to know what model is actually being used by `emmesns_test`;
and since you seem to want to use both `quantity` and `temperature` as factors,
even though they are numeric predictors, perhaps you want the model
`lm(growth_rate ~ factor(temperature) * factor(quantity) * quality, data = dat)`

Comment: Indeed, it seems that it was the solution of my problem, but when I add `cov.reduce = FALSE` to my `emmeans_test` call, an error occured : `Error in emmeans_test(., growth_rate ~ temperature, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni",  : 
  unused argument (cov.reduce = FALSE)`

Comment: So, maybe the quickest answer to your question is to replace `quantity` by `factor(quantity)` first. But doing so also changes the underlying model.